# BlackBerry to Code Home Screen As described below

Tags: blackberry

[image: Home Screen Image]

Hi Guys please see this is the Home screen i want to make in blackberry, i have tried putting in the vertical and horizontal field manager but i cant embed all together which give me result screen as mentioned above..
Please note the button are the Image button i have provided.. i want the structure code if any one can  help me out ..

```
Vertical Manager(main)
Horizontal Manager (for Two Buttons)
horizontal Manager (for Three Buttons)
Bitmap Field (for Image)
Add all three in Vertical Manager
and Vertical Manager to the Screen
```

i have tried Structure something like this:

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: your logic is correct. you can use margin/padding for this. You getting any errors ?

Comment: @Signare - nope but my whole screen get field with the single manager only and even huge scroll comes into picture...

Comment: which screen size you using ? Appoorva Faldu

Comment: You are going to need an extra VerticalFieldManager to put the button inside (even if there's only a field inside, you need it for centering). Also have a look at the [Advanced UI library](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Implement-advanced-buttons-fields-and-managers/ta-p/488276), maybe you find a manager there that can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have finally got the answer to my screen.

i have used the **Grid Manager** to make the fields display in order i wanted and i have used the **Image button Custom** to make it result up-to the mark..

thanks guys for all your support and help..

Answer (score 3):

I do not recommend using a series of Managers as you are trying to do.  Instead create a Manager that actually lays out the Fields tjhat you want, in the place that you want them.  Coded correctly you can use one Manager and have that Manager cope with the vagaries of the various size BlackBerry screens to make sure it looks OK regardless of the device your user has.  You can also factor in the size of the Buttons, which must be larger for touch screen devices, and more easily manage focus movement on track pad devices.

Yes, there is a bit of learning involved, but for me, the result will be better than trying to manage a series of VFMs and HFMs.

To understand how to do this, I recommend reviewing the following:

- http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Create-a-custom-layout-manager-for-a-screen/ta-p/442990
- http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/How-to-Extend-Manager/ta-p/446749

and also

- http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/MainScreen-explained/ta-p/606644

Note particularly the requirements in MainScreen to ensure that your Manager is told the real estate size that it has available.